# Select one column from a group by query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, subquery

I have this query in SQL Server which has all the condition and grouping I need:

```
SELECT 
    PersonnelID, Name, EmpStartCalc,
    MAX(PositionDetailsValidFromCalc) PD , 
    MAX(PositionHierValidFromCalc) PH, 
    MAX(PWAValidFromCalc) 
    PWA, 
    MAX(RowId) AS RowId
FROM 
    TV_IAMintegration_VW 
WHERE
    EmpStartCalc >= 20200101 
    AND EmpStartCalc <= 20200131 
    AND ((20200131 > PositionHierValidFromCalc     
GROUP BY 
    PersonnelID, Name, EmpStartCalc
ORDER BY 
    PersonnelID Asc
```

The result I get has some other columns too which are also important but I need Rowids separately to fetch complete records again from some other table like this

```
SELECT *
FROM Tv_IAM_NumSequence
WHERE RowId IN ("Row Ids returned from the above query")
```

Comment: I formatted the query but the `where` clause looks incomplete.

Comment: Do you mean to use in the same batch/sproc? Look at the `OUTPUT` clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple method is to use a CTE:

```
with cte as (
      <first query here without order by>
     )
select ns.*
from Tv_IAM_NumSequence ns
where ns.rowid in (select rowid from cte);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help it worked !
Great approach and minimized code <3

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Possibility 1
SELECT *
FROM Tv_IAM_NumSequence f1
inner join 
(
SELECT 
    PersonnelID, Name, EmpStartCalc,
    MAX(PositionDetailsValidFromCalc) PD , 
    MAX(PositionHierValidFromCalc) PH, 
    MAX(PWAValidFromCalc) PWA, 
    MAX(RowId) AS RowId
FROM TV_IAMintegration_VW 
WHERE
    EmpStartCalc between 20200101 AND 20200131 
    AND PositionHierValidFromCalc < 20200131    
GROUP BY PersonnelID, Name, EmpStartCalc
) f2
on f1.RowId =f2.RowId 

-- Possibility 2
with f2 as (
SELECT 
    PersonnelID, Name, EmpStartCalc,
    MAX(PositionDetailsValidFromCalc) PD , 
    MAX(PositionHierValidFromCalc) PH, 
    MAX(PWAValidFromCalc) PWA, 
    MAX(RowId) AS RowId
FROM TV_IAMintegration_VW 
WHERE
    EmpStartCalc between 20200101 AND 20200131 
    AND PositionHierValidFromCalc < 20200131    
GROUP BY PersonnelID, Name, EmpStartCalc
)
SELECT *
FROM Tv_IAM_NumSequence f1
inner join f2 on f1.RowId =f2.RowId
```